# How do I get a reference to the window object in a LWC Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to access to window object and their proprerties on a lwc component

is there any way to ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the raw `window` object in Salesforce, as this would allow components to interfere with other components in other domains. If you are using Locker Service, you'll be limited by the [SecureWindow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable) wrapper. In order to access more properties of `window`, you need to [enable Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable), which is far less restrictive in what you can access. Note that some properties will still be off-limits.